# Annotation data for northwind odata service

Tags: sapui5, web-ide

I am creating sapui application in sap web IDE. 
I am trying to connect Northwind Odata service in IDE. 
I am following this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiaPIDNV9JU

I have created services and configure it in IDE. but in last step it is asking me to Choose annotation data from one of the sources listed below.

step 3:
[image]

strp 4:
[image]

What do I need to add in annotaion ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the annotation file.

Annotation files are only relevant when you are working with Smart Controls, for example a Smart Form:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartform.SmartForm/samples

As of today the how-to-guide to create annotations in the SAP Gateway or the ABAP CDS views are not released. Maybe more after the TechEd October 2015 in Las Vegas.